# Native date/time widget in PhoneGap application on android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, datetimepicker

The Android embedded browser does not support the datetime-local input type, unlike the local chrome browser.

Is there a PhoneGap/Cordova plugin to delegate the date/time selection to the native widget and get back the result? I'm using PhoneGap 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two datepicker plugins available on the [phonegap plugin registry.](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)  The one for Android is here: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/134. You can follow the links on that page to the [actual repository](https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker/tree/3aeac69af2a7fdf14b2c1f6e060d7f8706728cf2) which looks like it has been updated to 3.x and being maintained. I'm not sure if it has support for everything that you are looking for, but according to the readme there is a `datetime` mode which is hopefully what you need. Try it out!

Comment: I have a problem with this plugin: After running "cordova plugin add https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker" I get the following error: "[Error: Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 3.0.0, failed version requirement: 2.9.0]". My Cordova version is 3.1.0-0.2.0

Comment: Ok, it seems that in the master branch there is version 0.0.2 which is based on cordova 2.9.0, in https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker/tree/3aeac69af2a7fdf14b2c1f6e060d7f8706728cf2 there is version 0.0.1, based on cordova 3.0.0

Comment: I have forked it ported it back to 3.0.0. Now it's half-working: The date picker is shown, but then I get the following error "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:929"

Comment: If you run a normal cordova app, you can see that message in the console a few times and it doesn't really do anything. Sometimes it signifies an error and sometimes cordova recovers just fine. I *think* it means that you (or the startup code) is either sending information from native to the javascript/browser before the browser is ready, or you are trying to interact with browser elements before the browser is ready.  Sorry, it's hard to describe because I really haven't quite figured it out yet.

Comment: Found the problem - cordova was at version 3.1.0 but the jar was at 3.0.0. Updating had solved the issue, and it works now. Pity there is no date/time dialog like in iOS...